reCAPTCHA の料金プランを選択する方法
こんにちは！
reCAPTCHA の料金プランの選び方を教えていただきたいです。
公式サイト（https://cloud.google.com/security/products/recaptcha?hl=ja）には、
reCAPTCHA Essentials、reCAPTCHA Standard、reCAPTCHA Enterpriseの3種類があると書かれています。
また、「使ってみる」「reCAPTCHA を管理する」からコンソールに移動し、reCAPTCHA の利用を開始できます。
しかし、コンソールで具体的にどのようにして料金プランを選択するのかが分かりません。
自分がどの料金プランで利用しているのかも確認できません。
実装が済んでからでないと選べないのでしょうか。
enter image description here
【もしかするとこれが原因かも】
・私は無料トライアルアカウントを利用しています。
・キーの設定は完了していません。
・最近料金の仕組みが変わったばかりで、ドキュメントやGUIの更新が追いついていない可能性があります。
【試したこと】
無料トライアルアカウントを利用してプロジェクトを作成し、reCAPTCHA のAPIを有効にしました。
デモサイトの設定を正しく完了しました。
通常のキーを発行しましたが、実装はしていません。
【期待】
reCAPTCHA の料金プランを選択したいです。
お手数をおかけしますが、ご教示いただけると助かります。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。
